# Old step definition is retained in WDIO Allure reports

Tags: webdriver-io, allure

I got a situation in webdriverIO allure reporter. When a feature file and step definition is defined for the first time and run, Allure report is generated as expected.
If the existing step is modified in feature and step def files, Allure report will show the old step and the newly modified step which is misleading.

Sharing an example of the above scenario,

Feature file: test.feature

```
Feature: Cucumber proof of concept

Background:
  Given I navigate to Google

Scenario: First Scenario
  When I search for "Formula 1"

Scenario: Second Scenario
  When I search for another result "Grand Prix"
```

Step def file: test.js

```
let {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function({Given, When, Then}) {
    Given(/^I navigate to Google$/, () => {
        browser.url('http://www.google.com')
    }); 

    When(/^I search for \"([^\"]*)\"$/, (text) => {
      browser.setValue('#lst-ib', text);
      browser.pause(5000);
    });

    When(/^I search for another result \"([^\"]*)\"$/, (text) => {
      browser.setValue('#lst-ib', text);
      browser.pause(5000);
    });

});
```

The allure report is as expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLNY.png)

Later if I modify step of the Second scenario to be,

```
Scenario: Second Scenario
  When I search for another new result "Grand Prix"
```

and generate Allure report, the old and the modified steps will be seen as shown below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6xeL.png)

I know that Allure2 supports history. But this is quite confusing and even the order in 2nd Scenario is messed up.

The only way to I was able to fix this was by deleting allure-results folder whenever there is a modification of a step. But I can't do that since I need the trend in Jenkins. Is there a way to get around this issue.

Platform:
Windows 10

package.json -

```
"webdriverio": "^4.12.0"
"wdio-cucumber-framework": "^1.1.1"
"wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.6.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use --clean option when generating allure report:

```
allure generate --clean
```